# Does Windows Azure blocks port 587?

Tags: linux, azure, exim, smtps

I am trying to use Exim4 as my email server on Windows Azure. I found Exim4 uses STARTTLS to do SMTPS, and the port number is 587. The problem is I opened 587 in Azure vm Endpoints, but I can not use the port, even telnet is not successful. so I'm wondering whether Azure blocks port 587 or my ISP blocks it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the end point as you have done **as well as** opening that port on the firewall inside the actual VM (Windows firewall or the equivalent on Linux, depending on which OS you are running).

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Windows, I'm running SMTP on Linux, I've opened ports on both firewalls and Endpoints.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear from your question, hence why I put it in brackets :) Please update your question to clarify that you have opened it on the firewall in the VM as well. I will leave the answer here in case someone else comes across it in a search. FWIW, Azure does not block arbitrary ports - if you open them in the endpoint *and* in your firewall on the VM, that traffic will get to you. If it is still isn't working, you need to look at the software on your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is not blocking port 587. If You use submission on STARTTLS try to open both 587/tcp and 587/udp. If no success, try to remove endpoint and recreate it (be sure that there is no misconfigured ACLs on endpoints). Also be sure that there is no blocking rules in iptables.